# Problem saving data from file .dat to an array

Tags: python, c, readfile

I have a program in C which makes a output file calles orbits_toy_model.dat as follows:

```
1.00000e-003     1.80000e-003   0.099799950033337   0.200099899983342
2.80000e-003     3.24000e-003   0.099439608731989   0.200279215634646
6.04000e-003     5.83200e-003   0.098790183270494   0.200600348178616
```

So I have done an easy program in python to read the data an save in an array:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
lines = loadtxt("C:/Users/Marta/OneDrive/Documents/Master/TFM/Code/EjemploIntegracion/prueba.dat", comments="#", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
```

This is working for a simple data file:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

But when I run the actual data file does not work it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marta/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 10, in <module>
    lines = loadtxt("C:/Users/Marta/OneDrive/Documents/Master/TFM/Code/EjemploIntegracion/orbits_toy_model.dat", comments="#", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
  File "C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1101, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1028, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1028, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 746, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

It seems that the format of my file is not in a proper way, there is any way to do it with this format in python?.

Comment: The data set is 4 numbers and after jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter (`delimiter=" "`) is what's causing the failure.

The default delimiter in [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is "Any whitespace". Since you're specifying a single space, it's using that as the delimiter, but then including *all other spaces* as part of the value.

If you leave off the `delimiter` parameter, you'll get the values as expected (where "test.dat" is your data as posted):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.loadtxt('test.dat', comments='#', unpack=False)
array([[0.001     , 0.0018    , 0.09979995, 0.2000999 ],
       [0.0028    , 0.00324   , 0.09943961, 0.20027922],
       [0.00604   , 0.005832  , 0.09879018, 0.20060035]])
```